# How to store images/files in a folder input through forms and save address to sql DB?

Tags: mysql, database, image, forms, image-gallery

I am designing a web site for a client and have a gallery page. I need to make an upload image option through the admin panel. I heard that storing the image directly in the sql DB is not efficient.

So what I want to know is that, how can I store the image I obtained from the user through the INPUT tag of HTML and store it in a folder say, UploadedImages and at the same time store the address of the upload image (URL) in my SQL DB?

Any answer with sample code will be of much use. Please advice me if there is much more efficient way. And sorry if this description seems to be lengthy. :)

And please guide me if the question is already answered. I dont find any post having a complete explanation about the process with the code..

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$target_path = "./upload/";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']); 
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) //Upload file to target path
 {
            $fileName = $_FILES['myfile']['name']; // Get Filename
            $fileSize = $_FILES['myfile']['size']; // Get filesize
            $fileType = $_FILES['myfile']['type']; // Get filetype
            echo "The picture ".  basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']) . " was uploaded successfully.";} else{
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }
```

Something like this.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `files`(`title`, `filename`, `size`, `type`, `categorie`) VALUES ('$_POST[title]', '$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$_POST[type]');");
```

This would be excatly what you need. An upload for a file - And additional an insert for your database (filename, size and so on...).

edit: added else : Error message and comments

edit 2: don´t forget:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

And:

```
<input type="file" name="myfile">
```

Comment: thanks! but when I add these codes to a blank index.php and run them i get the error below in my browser.

**
Notice: Undefined index: myfile in D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\gallery\index.php on line 26
**

  Same for myfile, title, fileName, fileType, fileSize and type variables too :( Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: use if isset post submit...put it in a "if" function that waits, til you submit the form in which the input type is. I didn´t want to write all what you exactly need...but this is the main part.

Comment: Ya it did work and it copied the files to the specified folder :) thanks! but the function jsAlert produces fatal error "Call to undefined function jsAlert() " so I removed them and now even though the file is copied to the folder when I query the mySQL DB it says zero rows found.. What am I missing? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: remove it and put an echo there...An upvote and accept of my answer would be nice.

Comment: I cant upvote as I dont have enough points :) could you please clarify me why is that the DB is not updated? I would be happy to get the problem solved :)

Comment: you need a database with a table named "files" first. Make sure you have all the fields you need inside the table..also categories for the galerie would be nice i think...but i don´t know what a structure you got...it´s shematic...it mustn´t work...you have to edit  and improve my shematic code.

Comment: Got it to work at last! used $result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error()); instead of the mysql_query and it worked :) thanks for the answer :) marking it as correct :)